# Searching a text file using List.FindAll and List.Find

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner in C#, trying to work on searching through a text file I'm just testing how it works on a quick and small app, the result should show the searched unique number followed by records of the name and phone number in a list box, for example (001   John   0123456789)

Here is my code:

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string match = "";
    try
    {
        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("Transactions.txt");
        List<string> TransList = new List<string>();
        {
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                TransList.Add(inputFile.ReadLine());
            }

            TransList = TransList.FindAll(x=>x.Equals(match)).ToList();
            string[] RecordsArray = TransList.ToArray();

            foreach (string record in RecordsArray)
            {
                if (match == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    DataListBox.Items.Add(RecordsArray[0]);
                    DataListBox.Items.Add(RecordsArray[1]);
                    DataListBox.Items.Add(RecordsArray[2]);
                }
            }

        inputFile.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the problem you’re seeing?

Comment: When you call `FindAll`, the value of `match` is an empty string. I think you want to set its value to `textBox1.Text` in the very beginning. Then, the `if(match == textBox1.Text)` part should be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, now it's returning the entered searching number only...

Comment: I suggest to include in the question what's the problem you are facing, otherwise it's difficult to write an answer for you.
Anyway, I suggest you to look at how List.FindAll works, on the official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=net-5.0